# Rails: sharing a controller across two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I have two models:

Student
  Classroom

Both of them have an action that does the **same exact thing**: it shows a report of daily activity. That is:

```
/students/1
/classrooms/1
```

Grabs activity for the model in question and displays it on the page.

In an attempt to dry this up, I created a `ReportsController` which extracts all the common logic of building a report.

If I leave the routes like this:

```
/students/1/report
/classrooms/1/report
```

Then I can have the `ReportsController#show` action look for `params` for `:student_id` or `:classroom_id` to determine which model type it is dealing with (for purposes of querying the database and rendering the correct view).

But I would prefer the URLs to be cleaner, so I also changed my `routes.rb` file to pass the `show` action for these models to the `reports#show` controller action:

```
resources :students, :classrooms do
  member do
    get :show, to: 'reports#show'
  end
end
```

This works, but I can no longer depend on `params` to identify which model to work with and which view to render.

**Question:** should I parse `request.fullpath` for the model? Or is there a better way to make a shared controller understand which model it is working with?

Comment: Can't you move all the logic to the model and keep 2 very simple controller actions that just call the methods in the model?

Comment: @abm how then do I avoid putting duplicate logic in the students and classrooms model? The logic is exactly the same: they query the events table for events with classroom_id = foo or student_id = bar.

Comment: If you are querying the `events` table, then your logic should go in the `Event` model.

Comment: @abm to me it makes more sense to say classroom.events vs. events.where(classroom_id: 5)

Answer (score 0):

Routing both show methods to the same controller method for code reuse is somewhat like banging a nail in with a dumptruck.

Even if you can find the resource by looking at the request url you would start splitting the ResortsController into a bunch of ifs and switches even before you got off the ground.

One solution is to add the common action in a module:

```
module Reporting
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def show
    # the Student or Classroom should be available as @resource
    render 'reports/show'
  end

  included do
    before_action :find_resource, only: [:show]
  end

  private

  def find_resource
    model = self.try(:resource_class) || guess_resource_class
    @resource = model.find(params[:id])
  end

  # This guesses the name of the resource based on the controller name.
  def guess_resource_class
    self.class.name[0..-11].singularize.constantize
  end
end
```

---

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController
  include Reporting
end

# Example where resource name cannot be deduced from controller
class PupilController < ApplicationController
  include Reporting
  private
  def resource_class
    Student
  end
end
```

`self.class.name[0..-11].singularize.constantize` is basically how Rails uses convention over configuration to load a `User` automatically in your UsersController even without any code.

But the most important key to DRY controllers is to keep your controllers skinny. Most functionality can either be moved into the model layer or delegated out to service objects.

Comment: action is a Rails idiom for a controller method. Models don't have actions - controllers do. Models have methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the common logic in the `Event` Model:

```
#Event Model
class Event < ...
      def self.your_event_method
         #self here will be either student.events or classroom.events 
         #depending on which controller called it
      end
end

class StudentsController < ...
  ...

  def show
    student = Student.find(params[:id])
    student.events.your_event_method
  end

end

class ClassroomsController < ...
  ...

  def show
    classroom = Classroom(params[:id])
    classroom.events.your_event_method
  end

end
```